# How to connect AWS Athena to an exists Hive Metastore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, hive-metastore

I need to integrate AWS Athena service with an exists Hive Metastore (not AWS Glue).

Can you please let me know how can I connect Athena to Hive Metastore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Athena works only with its own metastore or the related AWS Glue metastore.  It will not work with an external metastore.

However, you can set up multiple tables or databases on the same underlying S3 storage.  So if you wrote data to S3 using an external metastore, you could query those files with Athena, after setting up an appropriate database and table definition in Athena's metastore.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Athena just released a new feature (in preview now) that allows you to connect Athena to your Apache Hive Metastore. You can see the announcement [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/use-apache-hive-metastore-as-a-metadata-catalog-with-amazon-athena-preview/). Detailed steps to add the Hive Metastore connector are available in the Athena [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-to-data-source-hive.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to export the hive metadata to a file using the command

command="hive -f "+schema+"_tables.hql -S >> "+schema+".output"

where schema= to be exported and import the table definitions to Athena using groovy in python.

Instructions to set up groovy can be found in the link

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-big-data-blog/tree/master/aws-blog-athena-importing-hive-metastores

Comment: included the essential parts of the answer. HTH.